# spark Could not serialize lambda

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

- my programmer run normal at the begining.
- When i add spark BloomFilter, my programmer failed with `Could not serialize lambda`  after execute few batch.
- I try to registerKryo but also failed, what should i do, thank you

```
conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(
      Class.forName("org.apache.spark.util.sketch.BloomFilterImpl"),
      Class.forName("org.apache.spark.util.sketch.BloomFilter"),
      Class.forName("org.apache.spark.util.sketch.BitArray"),
      Class.forName("com.jk.utils.KafkaSink"),
      Class.forName("com.jk.utils.KafkaSink$$anonfun$1"), 
      Class.forName("org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer"),
      Class.forName("org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.RecordAccumulator"),
      Class.forName("org.apache.kafka.clients.ApiVersions"),
      Class.forName("org.json4s.JsonAST$JObject"),
      Class.forName("org.json4s.JsonAST$JArray"),
      Class.forName("org.json4s.JsonAST$JString"),
      Class.forName("org.json4s.JsonAST$JInt"),
      Class.forName("org.json4s.JsonAST$JBool"),
      Class.forName("org.json4s.JsonAST$JLong"),
      Class.forName("scala.math.BigInt"),
      Class.forName("java.math.BigInteger"),
      Class.forName("org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.KafkaMetric"),
      Class.forName("org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics"),
      Class.forName("org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.BufferPool")
    ))
```

**main code**

```
import org.apache.spark.util.sketch.BloomFilter

var bf: Broadcast[BloomFilter] = sc.broadcast(BloomFilter.create(10000000L))

kafkaDstream.foreachRDD(record => {
   val rdd = record.filter(msg=>{
       // filter with bloomFilter
       !bf.value.mightContainString(msg.value)
    })
    ...

   //save rdd to kafka
}
```

**kafka send util**

```
import java.util.Properties
import java.util.concurrent.Future

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.{KafkaProducer, ProducerRecord, RecordMetadata}
import org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

class KafkaSink[K, V](createProducer: () => KafkaProducer[K, V]) extends Serializable {
  lazy val producer = createProducer()

  def send(topic: String, key: K, value: V): Future[RecordMetadata] =
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord[K, V](topic, key, value))

  def send(topic: String, value: V): Future[RecordMetadata] =
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord[K, V](topic, value))
}


object KafkaSink {

  def apply[K, V](config: Map[String, Object]): KafkaSink[K, V] = {
    val createProducerFunc = () => {
      val producer = new KafkaProducer[K, V](config)
      sys.addShutdownHook {
        // Ensure that, on executor JVM shutdown, the Kafka producer sends
        // any buffered messages to Kafka before shutting down.
        producer.close()
      }
      producer
    }
    new KafkaSink(createProducerFunc)
  }

  def apply[K, V](config: Properties): KafkaSink[K, V] =
    apply(config.toMap)

  def getKafkaProducer(sparkSession: SparkSession, conf: CommonConf): Broadcast[KafkaSink[String, String]] = {
    val kafkaProducerConfig = {
      val properties = new Properties()
      properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", conf.getOrElse("kafka.bootstrap.servers", ""))
      properties.setProperty("key.serializer", conf.getOrElse("kafka.keySerializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"))
      properties.setProperty("value.serializer", conf.getOrElse("kafka.valueSerializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"))
      properties
    }
    sparkSession.sparkContext.broadcast(KafkaSink[String, String](kafkaProducerConfig))
  }
}
```

**error code**

```
Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not serialize lambda
Serialization trace:
metricValueProvider (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.KafkaMetric)
metrics (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
metrics (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.BufferPool)
free (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.RecordAccumulator)
accumulator (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer)
producer (com.jk.utils.MyKafkaUtils)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:101)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:508)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:651)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.write(MapSerializer.java:113)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.write(MapSerializer.java:39)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:575)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:79)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:508)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:575)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:79)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:508)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:575)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:79)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:508)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObjectOrNull(Kryo.java:629)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:86)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:508)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:575)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:79)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:508)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:651)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializationStream.writeObject(KryoSerializer.scala:241)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationStream.writeAll(Serializer.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializerManager.dataSerializeStream(SerializerManager.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$dropFromMemory$3.apply(BlockManager.scala:1524)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$dropFromMemory$3.apply(BlockManager.scala:1519)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore.put(DiskStore.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.dropFromMemory(BlockManager.scala:1519)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.org$apache$spark$storage$memory$MemoryStore$$dropBlock$1(MemoryStore.scala:473)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore$$anonfun$evictBlocksToFreeSpace$1.apply$mcVI$sp(MemoryStore.scala:499)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.evictBlocksToFreeSpace(MemoryStore.scala:490)
    at org.apache.spark.memory.StorageMemoryPool.acquireMemory(StorageMemoryPool.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.memory.StorageMemoryPool.acquireMemory(StorageMemoryPool.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.memory.UnifiedMemoryManager.acquireStorageMemory(UnifiedMemoryManager.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.memory.UnifiedMemoryManager.acquireUnrollMemory(UnifiedMemoryManager.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.reserveUnrollMemoryForThisTask(MemoryStore.scala:552)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIterator(MemoryStore.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1176)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1167)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1102)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1167)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.putIterator(BlockManager.scala:925)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.putSingle(BlockManager.scala:1492)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:240)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1329)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not serialize lambda
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ClosureSerializer.write(ClosureSerializer.java:69)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:575)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:79)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender$SenderMetrics$$Lambda$123/1592295195.writeReplace()
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2130)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ClosureSerializer.write(ClosureSerializer.java:60)
    ... 64 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I think i should work for you because you are broadcasting an object and not a lambda function. It works to me  in datastax spark cluster.

```
val kafkaSink = sc.broadcast(KafkaSink(kafkaOptionsProducer))
DStream
  .foreachRDD((rdd: RDD[String]) => {
    rdd.foreachPartition {
      recordsOfPartition: Iterator[String] => {
        val records = recordsOfPartition.toList
        records.foreach { record: String => {
          kafkaSink.value.sendMessage("realtime-output", record)
        }
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score -1):

temporarily use `df.write` to avoid `lambda` exception

```
rdd.toDF("value")
.write
.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", XXX)
.option("topic", XXX)
.save()
```